# How can I SELECT rows with MAX(date) and join each row with previous price

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Here is my sample dataset

```
id   thing  datetime      price
----|-----|------------|----------
1   | A   | 04/03/2009 |  399 
2   | B   | 04/03/2009 |  244
5   | C   | 04/03/2009 |  555
3   | D   | 04/03/2009 |  300
4   | A   | 03/03/2009 |  200
6   | B   | 03/03/2009 |  500
7   | C   | 24/12/2008 |  600
8   | D   | 01/01/2009 |  700
9   | A   | 01/03/2009 |  250
10  | B   | 01/03/2009 |  400
11  | C   | 12/12/2008 |  300
12  | D   | 20/01/2008 |  600
```

I need to get all rows from max date and then last price of each rows. Returning row should be like

```
id  thing  datetime      price  last price
---|-----|------------|--------|-----------
1  | A   | 04/03/2009 |  399   | 200
2  | B   | 04/03/2009 |  244   | 500
5  | C   | 04/03/2009 |  555   | 600
3  | D   | 04/03/2009 |  300   | 700
```

can I get this in single Sql? Need this in sql statement and sqlalchemy
Sry for any errors,
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using ? Don't involve the products that you don't use

Comment: @Pரதீப் I am using mysql right now, trying to manage it from sql-alchemy too

Comment: First store dates as dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might not be the best way, but it is a solution with SQL SERVER, please check it out

```
    with MY_TABLE as(

SELECT 1   id, 'A' thing , cast('20090403' as date) datetime,  399 price UNION ALL
SELECT 2   , 'B'   , '20090403' ,  244 UNION ALL
SELECT 5   , 'C'   , '20090403' ,  555 UNION ALL
SELECT 3   , 'D'   , '20090304' ,  300 UNION ALL
SELECT 4   , 'A'   , '20090303' ,  200 UNION ALL
SELECT 6   , 'B'   , '20090303' ,  500 UNION ALL
SELECT 7   , 'C'   , '20081224' ,  600 UNION ALL
SELECT 8   , 'D'   , '20090301' ,  700 UNION ALL
SELECT 9   , 'A'   , '20090301' ,  250 UNION ALL
SELECT 10  , 'B'   , '20090301' ,  400 UNION ALL
SELECT 11  , 'C'   , '20081212' ,  300 UNION ALL
SELECT 12  , 'D'   , '20080120' ,  600 

)



SELECT id,
        t1.thing,
        DATETIME,
        Y.price
FROM MY_TABLE t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT thing,price,rank()over(partition by thing order by datetime desc) as last_price
            from MY_TABLE) as Y on Y.thing= t1.thing and Y.last_price =2

WHERE datetime = (SELECT MAX(datetime) 
                  FROM MY_TABLE t2 
                  WHERE t1.thing = t2.thing)
```

Comment: this is working good but suppose B doesnt have any price of max date then it shouldnt be shown

Comment: You mean price =0 for B?, can you give me an example with the data you posted?

Answer (score 0):

I think a window function can solve your problem

```
select id, thing, datetime, price 
from (
select id, thing, datetime, price,  rank()over(order by datetime desc ) rk
from yourTable )
where rk = 1;
```